# Removing Hunk Interactively with git add --patch

Tags: git

I like to use git add --patch (and more recently, git add -i) to untangle my commits as well as verify that what I'm committing is *good to go*.

Once in a while I'll come across a hunk that might be an error logging statement, an extra newline (usually from erasing the aforementioned logging statement) - something that I'd actually rather remove entirely.

I don't want to stage and I'd also like to simply delete the hunk in question while it's right there in front me of (rather than jumping back to my editor and trying again). I want to apply the change against my working file as well.

Is there a way to do this?

---

What I've considered is using the edit hunk functionality.

This, in conjunction with the suggestion `hash` made below gets me a slightly nicer workflow than I have now.

I agree that it's a violation of the `git add`'s separation of concerns. OTOH it would just be so convenient ;P I sound like my boss ;)

Comment: Currently, the answer is "no".  It would be nice functionality to be able to use add -i and enumerate hunks, though.  eg, instead of yes/no to each hunk, you could generate a sequence of patches, and then commit would prompt for multiple log messages.  or if you had an option like 'stage/no-stage/stash' each hunk, instead of 'stage/don't stage' or 'stash/don't stash' (via stash -p)

Comment: Yeah, I think generally `git add` is not intended to be a way to edit work tree files, though you're right, it would be nice to be able to take care of it while you're there.

Comment: What I always thought would be cool to have 1-9 available as options during an `add -i`. Selecting `1` would add the hunk to the first commit, and so on. That would support the workflow whereby you could put all those comment changes in `1`, that fizzbuzz feature in `2`, etc. and hunks you don't want in `9`.  All in one pass.  Then just discard the last commit.  You'd have to work out how to get commit messages in there, but it sure would be useful.

Comment: `git checkout --patch` would do it with [git 2.4.0+](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout/2.4.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better than using reset hard HEAD, after committing all your valid hunks, you can just git checkout the file to reset it to what's recorded in the current branch.  That way it doesn't affect any other files.

Answer (score 3):

There's a thorough explanation of why git add does not do this from Git maintainer Junio [on the Git mailinglist](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=134506781932067&w=2) in response to a feature request.

Short version of his alternative process:

```
# start from N-commit worth of change, debug and WIP
git stash save -p debug ;# stash away only the debugging aid
# now we have only N-commit worth of change and WIP
git stash save -p wip ;# stash away WIP

git add -p ;# prepare the index for the next commit
git stash save -k ;# save away the changes for later commits

git commit
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add to index whatever you want, commit, then reset hard HEAD, then what was not in the index is lost.

Comment: This is not a true solution. The OP mentions untangling commits, and therefore likely has other desirable modifications in the work tree which a reset/stash would kill.

Comment: It is what he can do to get what he want, not what he want to be able to do, yes.